# pareto ranking using Pyevolve

Tags: python, genetic-algorithm, evolutionary-algorithm, pyevolve

I am currently using Pyevolve package to solve some Genetic Algorithms problems. I am wondering is there any examples using Pareto ranking in Pyevolve package, since I have multi evaluation functions.

If not exists, could you plz provides some pseudo code of Pareto ranking algorithms. I want to implement it by myself.

Thank you!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on the last release documentation there effectively doesn't seem to be any Pareto ranking package in Pyevolve.

If you want to implement it yourself, you should check NSGA-II which is one most well known and best working algorithm for multi-objective optimization. The original article, containing pseudocode, can be found here : http://sci2s.ugr.es/docencia/doctobio/2002-6-2-DEB-NSGA-II.pdf

If you want to develop multi-objective genetic algorithms in Python and since Pyevolve development is quite moribund, I would recommend you to check out a more versatile framework named DEAP : http://deap.googlecode.com/. The framework already includes everything you need to do multi-objectives GAs, and provides many examples of how this can be done (NSGA-II is already implemented in DEAP). The transition from Pyevolve should be easy as the documentation is quite complete. You can also get in touch with the developers, they answer questions very quickly.

Comment: Thank you @CmdNtrf, your answer is what I expected. DEAP is really good, easy to use and contains everything I need.